# Chance of hitting 3 of a kind

Tags: odds, all-in

Playing with play money online, blinds are 500/1000. Both villain and I have deep stacks, around 230,000 for me and roughly 180,000 for him.

I have `AA`, he raises, I 3-bet and he 4-bets all-in. At this point I figure he has a pocket pair but since I have aces, I call him.

The flop comes, he hits a King and makes it 3 of a kind with his `KK`. Needless to say I lost.

Was calling the right thing to do? What are the chances of hitting a 3 of a kind before the flop?

Comment: Calling was definitely right. The chances of hitting 3OAK **before** the flop is 0%. ;)

Comment: just a cooler - he never folding KK and you never folding AA

Comment: Sure. What's the chance of hitting 3 OAK on the flop, turn or river?

Comment: What were the bet/raise sizes? Although it's (usually) completely fine to call any bet/raise with AA, I do find it strange that your opponent is already all-in at the 4-bet when both players are around 200 BB deep. If either of you had gone slower, you may have had the chance to get out after the flop.

Comment: When you have the best hand, you never want to fold.  If you find yourself in a situation where you're tempted to fold AA preflop, that means you're playing at too high-stakes a table.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely calling is the correct play for you. You are heads up with the best starting hand.

The odds of hitting a set on the flop is about 11%.

AA wins about 80% of the time vs KK.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer from Herb.  Give him the the check.

AA is the best possible hand - always call pre flop

From combinations make trips on the flop

combin(2,1) * combin(48,2) / combine(50,3) = 11.5% = 7.7:1

If you add in quads  11.8% = 7.5:1